# Determine which role is restricting access in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I've got a Sitecore Multilist that has several pre-selected items on it.  Certain users aren't able to see the items on the list, because they don't have read access to the items.

The problem I've run into is that these users have some 12 roles and I can't figure out which one is restricting their read access to the items in the list.  Is there an easy way to figure out which role needs to be modified to give them read access to these items?

I'm running Sitecore 7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Sitecore Access Viewer application from Sitecore Desktop (Sitecore -> Security Tools -> Access Viewer).

1. Select chosen user
2. Find item which is not allowed for that user
3. Click on the 'Read' column.
4. You will see explanation why access is denied in right column

[image]